Browser Runtime error for vite prod build: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'reactExports.useContext(...)' as it is null
I have a React component package that uses react-router-dom that is built using rollup. In the component package I have added it as a peer-dependency and included it in the external section of the rollup config.
In my UI package, which is dependent on the component package, I'm using vite to build. When I run vite in dev mode, all is fine. The vite production build works fine but I get the runtime error when loading it in the browser.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'reactExports.useContext(...)' as it is null.
    at index.js:11:2890
    at Nh (react-dom.production.min.js:160:137)
    at Yi (react-dom.production.min.js:192:57)
    at Vk (react-dom.production.min.js:293:275)
    at Uk (react-dom.production.min.js:279:389)
    at Tk (react-dom.production.min.js:279:320)
    at Ik (react-dom.production.min.js:279:180)
    at Nk (react-dom.production.min.js:270:88)
    at Ek (react-dom.production.min.js:272:300)
    at jg (react-dom.production.min.js:127:105)

My App.tsx in the UI package is as follows:
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { AppContainer } from "app-libs-ui/components";
import { store } from "app-libs-ui/redux";
import { UserService } from "app-libs-ui/services";

import "@flaticon/flaticon-uicons/css/all/all.css";

import './index.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

// Custom imports:
import { SideBarSections } from "./model/custom/sidebar/SideBarSections.js";
import { typeSpecs } from "./model/custom/index.js";
import { categorySpecs } from "./model/custom/index.js";
// End Custom imports

const appContainer = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(appContainer!);


export const renderApp = () => root.render(
    <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AppContainer 
                typeSpecs={typeSpecs}
                categorySpecs={categorySpecs}
                sideBarSections={SideBarSections}
            />
        </Provider>
    </Router>
);

UserService.initKeycloak(renderApp);

UI package vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
    root: 'src',
    build: {
        outDir: '../build',
        assetsDir: '',
        sourcemap: true,
        emptyOutDir: true,
        commonjsOptions: {
            exclude: [
                "common-models-ts",
                "app-libs-ui",
                "app-libs-ui/*",
                "app-models-specification-json",
                "app-models-specification-json/*",
                "app-models-specification-ts",
                "app-models-specification-ts/*",
                "onchaindata-models-specification-ts",
                "onchaindata-models-specification-ts/*",
            ]
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        react(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-router-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-router-dom'),
        }
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: [
            "react-router-dom",
            "common-models-ts",
            "app-libs-ui",
            "app-models-specification-ts",
            "onchaindata-models-specification-ts",
        ]
    },
    publicDir: 'assets',
    server: {
        hmr: {
            clientPort: 443,
            overlay: false,
        }
    },
    esbuild: {
        logOverride: { 'this-is-undefined-in-esm': 'silent' }
    }
});

Component package rollup config:
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import yaml from '@rollup/plugin-yaml';
import fs from 'fs';
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const extensions = ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx'];

const getFiles = (entry, extensions = [], excludeExtensions = []) => {
    let fileNames = [];
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync(entry);

    dirs.forEach((dir) => {
        const path = `${entry}/${dir}`;

        if (fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory()) {
            fileNames = [
                ...fileNames,
                ...getFiles(path, extensions, excludeExtensions),
            ];

            return;
        }

        if (!excludeExtensions.some((exclude) => dir.endsWith(exclude))
            && extensions.some((ext) => dir.endsWith(ext))
        ) {
            fileNames.push(path);
        }
    });

    return fileNames;
};


export default {
    input: [
        './src/index.ts',
        './src/index.css',
        ...getFiles('./src/components', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/constants', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/enums', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/errors', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/lib', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/model', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/pages', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/redux', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/services', extensions),
        ...getFiles('./src/util', extensions),
    ],
    output: {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'esm',
        preserveModules: true,
        preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
        sourcemap: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal(),
        nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, preferBuiltins: true, browser: true }),
        json(),
        yaml(),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            tsconfig: './tsconfig.build.json',
            declaration: true,
            declarationDir: 'dist',
        }),
        postcss(),
        terser(),
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom'],
};

Any ideas what can be going wrong here? It's got me stumped as it works fine when running vite --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 but fails at runtime in the browser on the production build.

The error "Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'reactExports.useContext(...)' as it is null" typically means you are attempting to use some React-Router-DOM component outside a router which provides the context. What is index.js:11:2890 of the first stop in the stacktrace? Can you also try a non-production build so the stacktrace uses more meaningful names?

When I checked the source for index.js, it turns out that the react-router-dom package was still loaded in the component library. I'd actually already fixed this, and then noticed an old copy of App.tsx in the source. The prod/staging instance was referring to an incorrect volume mount pointing to the wrong code base. All good now. I think this was caused by the multiple instance of react-router-dom in the bundle.
